# distribution related to standard normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

we know that $(X_k)$ i.i.d, $N(0,1)$, then what is the distribution of the vector
$(\frac{X_1}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2}},\frac{X_2}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2}},\cdots,\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2}})$

I Know that the vector sums up to 1, but it seems not helpful. I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Are you looking for the distribution of each component, or the distribution of the norm?

Comment: not the norm nor each component, but the joint distribution of all the component.

Comment: By the invariance of the normal vector $(X_k)$ by rotations, this is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere.